# Validate an array from html form

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a html form. Here is a fragment:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="answer_text_1">Текст ответа 1</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="answer_text_1" rows="3"
              name="answer_text[0]"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="answer_text_2">Текст ответа 2</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="answer_text_2" rows="3"
              name="answer_text[1]"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="answer_text_3">Текст ответа 3</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="answer_text_3" rows="3"
              name="answer_text[2]"></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see I try to give an array in `answer_text`. Next I am trying to validate it with the help of Laravel Request and set my own error messages. Here is code of the Request

```
class CreateQuestionRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'question' => 'required|string',
            'answer_text.0' => 'required|string',
            'answer_text.1' => 'required|string',
            'answer_text.2' => 'required|string',
            'answer_text.*' => 'distinct',
            'answer' => 'required',
            'cost' => 'required|integer',
            'rating' => 'required|integer',
            'duration' => 'required|integer',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'question.required' => 'Текст вопроса не установлен.',
            'answer_text.distinct' => 'У вас есть одинаковые варианты ответа.',
            'answer_text.0' => 'Не указан первый вариант ответа.',
            'answer_text.1' => 'Не указан второй вариант ответа.',
            'answer_text.2' => 'Не указан третий вариант ответа.',
            'cost.required' => 'Не указана цена вопроса.',
            'rating.required' => 'Не указана сложность вопроса.',
            'duration.required' => 'Не указано количество времени, данное пользователю на ответ',
            'cost.integer' => 'Цена вопроса должна быть числом',
            'rating.integer' => 'Сложность вопроса должна быть числом',
            'duration.integer' => 'Время на ответ должно быть задано числом',
        ];
    }
}
```

But if I the fields `answer_text` are empty I see follownig:

[image]

This is a default Laravel errors. But I would like to see my messages from

```
 public function messages()
{
    return [
       // ...
        'answer_text.0' => 'Не указан первый вариант ответа.',
        'answer_text.1' => 'Не указан второй вариант ответа.',
        'answer_text.2' => 'Не указан третий вариант ответа.',
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this for custom error messages

[Custom error messages in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages)

You need this `answer_text.0` when you displaying error.

Comment: Sorry, but where I need it? I already have it)) See the last code listing.

Comment: try with this `'answer_text.*' => 'required|string'` and for displaying error in view use `@if ($errors->has('name')) 
        <span class="text-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif`

Comment: Ohhh, sorry. I just forget specify rule for messages array. It was `'answer_text.2' => 'error message',` but need `'answer_text.2.required' => 'error message',`. And it works nice) Thank you!